# WIndows Combobox AutoComplete - can you set the duration of typing time?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

We use ComboBoxes in our Winforms app with type-ahead functionality enabled (AutoCompleteMode property = Suggest, AutoCompleteSource = ListItems).  When the user starts typing, the ComboBox will jump ahead to match what has been typed, as intended.  But if the user pauses for a second or two in the middle of their typing, the AutoComplete "resets" and the next character they type will then be used as a new starting point for the autocomplete.

For example, say they type "Bike" - the ComboBox will jump to the "Bikes" entry in the ComboBox.  But say they type "Bik", then pause for a few seconds, then type "e" - the ComboBox will forget about the typed "Bik" and jump to the first entry to start with "e".

Our users have expressed a desire to extend the amount of time in which they get to type before it "resets".   Does anyone know if there's a way to configure this or code around it?

Comment: What is the AutoCompleteSource?

Comment: AutoCompleteSource is ListItems.

Comment: Looks like this can't be done with the default implementation. Have you seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No luck, the [IAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292%28VS.85%29.aspx) API used by the ComboBox does not have any such option.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out by using .net reflector on the System.Windows.Forms namespace and looking for the control in code.